# Have any countries besides France banned pro-Palestine demonstrations recently?

Tags: france, protests, comparative-politics, palestine

Reuters [reports](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/france-bans-pro-palestinian-protests-citing-risk-disturbances-public-order-2023-10-12/#:%7E:text=Two%20pro%2DPalestinian%20demonstrations%20in,Palestinian%20demonstrations%20across%20the%20country.):

> French police used teargas and water cannon to break up a banned rally in support of the Palestinian people in Paris on Thursday, as President Emmanuel Macron urged the French to remain united and refrain from bringing the Israel-Hamas conflict home.
>
> Macron's interior minister had earlier banned pro-Palestinian protests, saying they were "likely to generate disturbances to public order". [...]
>
> "There is no 'Yes, but'. Those who confuse the Palestinian cause with the justification of terrorism are making a moral, political and strategic mistake."

Clearly the UK hasn't followed suit, as [there's](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/crime/march-for-palestine-london-gaza-rally-israel-hamas-met-police-b1113424.html) one such rally in London as I'm writing this (with heavy police presence though).

So, have any other countries followed France's suit, and banned pro-Palestinian demonstrations (considering them inherently pro-Hamas, in this context)?

Comment: Are you asking about blanket bans? German authorities have banned a number of demonstrations, but that was, as is usual under German law, always for individual events.

Comment: @ccprog: if the individual bans are numerous enough, they could be construed as a "stealth" ban of higher order, but I have no idea if that's the case in Germany. I realize that in many countries such decisions are decentralized, unlike in France.

Comment: Not quite possible, since every ban has to cite individual reasons, and those can be challenged in court.

Comment: @ccprog The German situation starts being complicated. https://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2023-10/krieg-israel-gaza-hamas-liveblog#event_id=emavDUzq5enQ5SR9JtLM Aparently in Cologne a court reversed a ban on a pro Palistinian demonstration so there is no universal ban (imposed by individual cities).

Comment: @quarague Absolutely normal. The ban, its reversal, court decision in an individual case is business as usual. I have found no indication there ever was a universal ban (Allgemeinverfügung).

Comment: @quarague ...Anyway, each registrant of a demonstration would still have the right to challenge the ban of his gathering at court, which makes such a form of ban unatractive for the authorities. See [this discussion](https://kripoz.de/2022/03/31/corona-spaziergaenge-versammlungsrechtliche-verbote-in-gestalt-der-allgemeinverfuegung/), section III for some legal details. See also [1 BvR 208/22](https://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/SharedDocs/Entscheidungen/DE/2022/01/rk20220131_1bvr020822.html), esp. RN 7.

Comment: Wouldn't a better question be *why* has France banned pro-palestinian protests?

Comment: @sfxedit: isn't that in the quote? I mean unless you want to inject alternative explanations, besides the official one...

Comment: @Fizz *likely to generate disturbances to public order* is the general excuse used worldwide to shut down all political protests. It's vague and doesn't tell us anything of value. What characteristic of French politics and culture make *this* particular protest so dangerous (from the PoV of the Maacron Govt.)? Does France have a history of anti-semitism? Do Muslim and Jews there have a history of tension due to the Palestine-Israel issue? All that would be interesting to know ...

Comment: @sfxedit just to answer your points: France has a history of antisemitism as well as of islamophobia, and France also has both the largest population of Jewish people and of Muslims in Europe. Consequently the Israel-Palestine conflict is often cause for serious tensions in France (a teacher was [murdered recently](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-67101089)). The current Macron govt leans pro-Israel, but the left leans pro-Palestine. So it's possible that this protest ban was politically motivated, but the public order justification may also be reasonable.

Comment: It's worth noting that it was [incorrectly reported](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/10/12/europe/france-ban-pro-palestinian-intl/index.html) that France bans all pro-Palestine protests. This would be illegal of course, a large demonstration was allowed [last Sunday](https://www.france24.com/en/france/20231022-gaza-paris-is-with-you-thousands-join-pro-palestine-rally-in-french-capital) and took place peacefully.

Comment: @Erwan: because of a legal decision watering down the gov't decision, IIRC. https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/french-court-upholds-government-instruction-ban-all-pro-palestine-protests-2023-10-18/ Legal decision which came about 4 days after I posted this Q, I might add.

Comment: @Fizz sorry I missed that, I guess I couldn't imagine that this govt would be so ignorant about free speech.

Comment: Pro-Palestine protests remain banned in Berlin, but not the whole of Germany.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Hungary. Although it was [described](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/hungary-ban-rallies-supporting-terrorist-organisations-pm-orban-2023-10-13/) just as a ban on pro-Hamas demonstrations:

> October 13
>
> Hungary will not allow any rallies supporting "terrorist organisations," Prime Minister Viktor Orban told public radio on Friday, adding that all Hungarian citizens should feel safe, regardless of their faith or origin. [...]
>
> A rally supporting Palestine was called for 1400 GMT outside the Hungarian Foreign Ministry in Budapest on Facebook.
>
> "There have been attempts even in Hungary," Orban said, without directly referring to the planned event. "But we will not allow sympathy rallies supporting terrorist organisations as that would entail a terror threat to Hungarian citizens."

And [then](https://hungarytoday.hu/still-a-no-permit-for-pro-palestinian-demonstration-denied/)

> November 8
>
> Still a “NO”- Permit for Pro-Palestinian Demonstration in Budapest Denied
>
> The Budapest Police Headquarters (BRFK) has banned a rally announced in connection with the armed conflict between the Hamas terrorist organization and Israel, the police said on their website on Wednesday, adding that there was reason to fear that the event would lead to violence.
>
> The BRFK wrote on police.hu that the rally had been announced by a private citizen for November 22 in the second district of Budapest.
> They explained that similar rallies in many cities in Europe and around the world have recently ended in violence, so there is reason to fear that this could endanger public order, public safety, and the physical safety of those present in Hungary, and therefore the Budapest Police Headquarters has banned the rally under the law on the right of assembly.

If I'm reading that right, no pro-Palestine demonstration took place in Budapest in the past month. I'm not sure about other Hungarian cities.

They did hold/allow a large [pro-Israel rally](https://hungarytoday.hu/budapest-march-in-stark-contrast-with-pro-hamas-celebrations-in-europe/) though.

---

BTW, as this might be lost in the [lengthy] comments, the ban in France [was](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/french-court-upholds-government-instruction-ban-all-pro-palestine-protests-2023-10-18/) watered down soon thereafter.

> Fance's highest administrative court stated on Wednesday [Oct 18] that pro-Palestinian protests must be banned on a case-by-case basis, while upholding the validity of an instruction from the French interior minister banning all pro-Palestinian protests.
>
> In a note sent to regional police authorities, dated Oct. 12, the interior minister had ordered that "pro-Palestinian protests, because they are likely to generate disturbances to public order, must be banned".
>
> The appeal on the blanket ban instruction was brought by the organisation Comite Action Palestine, arguing that a total and absolute ban is not justified and encroaches on freedom of expression and assembly.
>
> The Conseil d'Etat upheld the validity of the note but said that local authorities could not ban a protest based solely on the note or the fact that a protest is in support of Palestinians.
>
> The Conseil d'Etat said in its decision that while the judges regret the approximative wording of the minister's note, it's intention was to instruct authorities to "ban all protests that support the Palestinian cause, that publicly justify or valorise, directly or indirectly, terrorist acts like those committed in Israel on October 7 by Hamas members."

Subsequently a pro-Palestine rally [was](https://www.france24.com/en/france/20231022-gaza-paris-is-with-you-thousands-join-pro-palestine-rally-in-french-capital) allowed in Paris on Oct 22. (Hat tip to Erawn for pointing out this rally.)